# Connect to SQL Server with different user

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I want to connect with PowerShell to SQL Server with a different user.

My code:

```
$SQLServer = "Server"
$SQLDBName = "DB"
$uid = "User"
$pwd = "PWD"

$SqlQuery = "select * from tblCalc where field_id = 367;"

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
```

I get this error:

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'User'."  
At line:14 char:1  
+ $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException  
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Comment: Also, check SQL Server's Errorlog  for login failures. Aaron Bertrand has a [nice list](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456) of login error codes and their explanations.

Comment: You should check SQL Server errorlog where the cause of "login failed" is written explicitly